# What does underline on a group mean in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

What does the underline on a group mean in Illustrator's Layers panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the group is acting as the clipping region of a clipping mask or that the group has a transparency mask.